# Recent Installed Pipelight for Mint 16 — Two version of Flash Issue

Tags: linux-mint, firefox, cinnamon, adobe-flash

I recently installed Pipelight in Linux Mint 16 Cinnamon and now I have two version of Flash. I only have Firefox 28 and no other browser. I followed the instruction from the FDS-Team (http://fds-team.de/cms/pipelight-installation.html#section_2_3) to remove the symlink of the NPAPI Linux plugin and replace it with a symlink to Pipelight. Opened the terminal and entered these command lines:

```
sudo update-alternatives --install "/usr/lib/mozilla/plugins/flashplugin-alternative.so" "mozilla-flashplugin" /usr/lib/pipelight/libpipelight-flash.so
sudo update-alternatives --set mozilla-flashplugin /usr/lib/pipelight/libpipelight-flash.so
```

I still both version of flash enabled. How can I disable the native flash 11 and just use the flash 13 from Pipelight? or How can I remove the native flash 11 completely?

Comment: Can you go do the "Add-ons" section from the Firefox menu, select the Plugins panel, and tell the Flash 11 to "Never Activate"?

Answer (score 1):

Not if you have two version of flash. What happens is that if you disable one flash version, for some reason it will disable both version.  Firefox only recognizes the whole flash packages and thinks it's both the same. Firefox, you can not individually disable specific versions of a plugin, you can only disable the whole plugin with all it's versions.  The command lines that was described is to tell Firefox which version to use but I can't the command lines together.